# How to Define New Todo Command Which Still Takes Options

Tags: macros, todonotes

I am using the package `todonotes` in order to handle my TODOs. As written in the [manual](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf), one can define a custom TODO command like that:

```
\newcommand{\feedbackRequired}[1]{\todo[color=red!70]{#1}}
```

This works in general if one uses it without any options:

```
\feedbackRequired{Do I have to do that, supervisor?}
```

But unfortunately, it is not possible to use the new command and give it some extra options like that:

```
\feedbackRequired[inline]{Do I have to do that, supervisor?}
```

This will break the output. The tex file will still be compiled, but the TODO note output in the PDF is broken:

[image]

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Your command is not defined for optional arguments

Comment: Please add a MWE in order to see which packages etc. you use otherwise. Consider a retag to `macros`, as the problem is not directly to `todonotes` but rather to the usage of `macros` and optional parameters

Comment: I will next time. This time I already thought that this will be an easy pick for people who really understand LaTeX :-)

Comment: Yes, I can understand that, but guessing around about packages, documentclass... it's tedious. I have to admit, however, that the principial issue of your requestion is not related to a particular class/package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an optional argument, you must use

```
\newcommand{\feedbackRequired}[2][]{\todo[color=red!70,#1]{#2}}
```

The second `[]` holds the optional argument, in this case it is predefined to be empty, but later on, in your example, it will be `inline`. Your actual note is contained in the 2nd argument.

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{todonotes}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%


\newcommand{\feedbackRequired}[2][]{\todo[color=red!70,#1]{#2}}



\begin{document}

\feedbackRequired{Do I have to do that, supervisor?}

\feedbackRequired[inline]{Do I have to do that, supervisor?}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [One day baby, I will understand LaTeX. Oh baby, I will understand...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A16VcQdTL80) Thanks, mate!